# Is it possible to use a spherical collision component in UDK?

Tags: udk

I have an object in UDK, which has a `SkeletalMesh`. At certain times in the game, I want this object to continue rendering the `SkeletalMesh`, but I'd like it to use spherical collision temporarily.

After reading a bunch about `PrimitiveComponents`, my understanding is that UDK supports cylindrical and box-like collision, but not spherical without using a static mesh.

EDIT:
What I have now is a `StaticMesh` with a material that makes it invisible. I've added a `StaticMeshComponent` to my `Pawns`. I can shut off the Pawn's collision, and turn on the StaticMesh collision. But it doesn't respond to impulses. I figure I'm missing something in how you turn on the RigidBody thingy.

```
CylinderComponent.SetActorCollision(false, false);
SetPhysics(PHYS_RigidBody);
RBCollisionComponent.SetStaticMesh(RBCollisionMesh);
RBCollisionComponent.AddImpulse(InImpulse);
RBCollisionComponent.WakeRigidBody();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I just needed to set the CollisionComponent of the Pawn to be the StaticMeshComponent, and set all the collision channels properly. Also, changing the StaticMesh to use simplified spherical collision helped.

```
CylinderComponent.SetActorCollision(false, false);
SetPhysics(PHYS_RigidBody);

CollisionComponent = RBCollisionComponent;
RBCollisionComponent.SetStaticMesh(RBCollisionMesh);
RBCollisionComponent.WakeRigidBody();
RBCollisionComponent.SetRBChannel(RBCC_Pawn);
RBCollisionComponent.SetRBCollidesWithChannel(RBCC_Default, true);
RBCollisionComponent.SetRBCollidesWithChannel(RBCC_Pawn, true);
RBCollisionComponent.SetRBCollidesWithChannel(RBCC_Vehicle, false);
RBCollisionComponent.SetRBCollidesWithChannel(RBCC_Untitled3, false);
RBCollisionComponent.SetRBCollidesWithChannel(RBCC_BlockingVolume, true);
```